# Compact code for finding integer's factor in the form of a power of 2

Tags: c#, math, bit-manipulation

Recently I have encountered an interesting problem at one of the online contests; in the contests there is no formulation of the problem, only unit tests are present to describe it. The language for solution is C#. The solution is graded by the **size of bytecode** generated (I don't know the specific compiler being used, but most probably it's MS VS 2013), and the running **performance does not matter**.

The problem (in my formulation): you are given an signed integer. Find its largest factor in the form of

```
2^n, n >= 1
```

if there are no such factors return 1.

I ended up with the following solution:

```
int Puzzle(int n) {
   if (n == 0) { 
     return n;
   }
   int shift = 0;
   while (((1 << shift) & n) == 0) {
     shift++;
   }

   return 1 << shift;    
}
```

In my solution I am counting the number of zero positions until first 1 is encountered.

While this solution is accepted by the system, the quality of the solution is graded quite low.

Is there a way to solve this problem with the code, that would be compiled in more compact bytecode?

**UPD**: thanks to rici and some meditation I've upgraded my solution to

```
n - n^(n&-n)
```

Comment: Since you are basically playing Code Golf, you may want to ask on that SE.

Comment: not sure if it is completely on-topic for SO as your code already solves "practical" part of the problem. To continue your research use search term "bit hacks". I.e. http://www.bing.com/search?q=bit+hacks+highest+power+of+2 gives some promising links.

Comment: The generic term for these kind of algorithms is "bit hacks".  Googles well, it is a popular pastime for programmers that don't mind writing impenetrable code.  Not typically your best pair programmer or team mate.

Comment: why downvoting? The contest is closed now, I am not using SO to cheat.

Comment: @undefined But now, you know what to include when asking a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one I would try is `n&-n`. You might enjoy figuring out how it works.

Comment: great, computing the lowest bit set in one step makes the solution much more compact. thanks!

Comment: It probably makes the solution faster, too. At least, I've always worked on that assumption.